# Statut bar reappears when User click on uploading file option in an UIWebview on IOS7

Tags: user-interface, uiwebview, ios7, statusbar

I hide de statut bar in My IOS app. Since IOS7, when a user is in a UIWebView and click on a field with upload features (images for exemple), the statut bar appears alone.

How can I correct this bug ?